# Access data in child component in angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

I have a Angular 1.5 component, addProductComponent, with template like this:

```
<form>
    <details-component></details-component>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' ng-click='$ctrl.submit()'>
</form>
```

In `<details-component>`, there are inputs which define the properties of a product object. It is purely an html template that needs to be shared with other components.

My questions is: When I submit the form, how can I get the product details data from the `<details-component>` without breaking the input/output principles of Angular component architecture?

Comment: design the `details-component` to bind to an object passed in from the form, like `<details-component details='$ctrl.details'>`

Comment: Then update the "details" object within <details-component>? Would it not be violating the input/output design practices recommended by Angular? This is from the Angular document: 
"Components should never modify any data or DOM that is out of their own scope."
"For components however, only the component that owns the data should modify it, to make it easy to reason about what data is changed, and when."

Comment: the angular examples use one way binding `<` with an `onUpdate` function to send the data back out to the parent.

Comment: Currently I am using event to broadcast to <details-component> where the event is caught and callback method is called. The details component has something like this:

bindings: { onSubmit: '&'},
controller: function(){
    $scope.$on('event', function(){
        this.onSubmit({ details: detailsObject});
});
}

It works but I think it is overkill for such a simple and common requirement. Perhaps your suggestion is the valid solution.

Comment: as I read the angular documentation for Components again, and look at the "trivial" example that they provide, it seems like it's really unnecessarily complex.  I understand the idea behind controlling data access, but it's almost like components encourage you to not use two way binding at all, even though that's what angular was built around.

Comment: Another problem with my shared <details-component> is the form validation. In the details component template, I want to use the form validation bindings like: 
        <span ng-show="userAddForm.$submitted><span ng-show="userAddForm.email.$error.required">Email is required</span>
        </span>

because the userAddForm is attached to the parent $scope. The details component has no access to it. 
I also tried to bind the form to it but it is not working.
Any suggestions on how to solve this? 
Thanks